# Reference Request - New proof of Ribet's level lowering by Khare and Wintenberger

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, galois-representations

I'm currently following the [note](https://gauss.math.yale.edu/%7Erz289/Galois_reps.pdf) of Sug Woo Shin's course at Berkeley with notes taken by Rong Zhou. In Section 24.3 (Page 86), Ribet's level lowering theorem is stated:

> [Theorem 24.7] $E = E_{a^{\ell}, b^{\ell}}$, suppose that $E$ is semistable, weight 2 of level $N$, $\overline{\rho}_{E,\ell}$ unramified outside $2\ell$, $\overline{\rho}_{E, \ell}|_{G_{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}}$ has crystalline lift with HT weight 0,1. Then $\overline{\rho}_{E,\ell}$ is weight 2 and of level 2.

(P.S. Here $E_{a^{\ell}, b^{\ell}}$ is the Frey curve constructed by a "solution" of Fermat's equation $x^{\ell}+y^{\ell}=z^{\ell}$.)

In Section 24.3 of the note, it is claimed that "**there is an alternative method due to Khare and Wintenberger**" and the sketch of proof is given in the note (Section 24.3, Page 86). So could someone provide some detailed references on this new proof?

Thank you all for commenting and answering.

Comment: The main point is Theorem 3.3 of their paper "On Serre's conjecture on mod $p$ representations of $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$" which gives the existence of a minimal lift $\rho$. After that one applies a suitable modularity lifting theorem to $\rho$ to deduce that it is modular.

Comment: @naf Thank you for your comments! I shall look into that :)